# Naming a template

Tags: php, html, templates

A page is generated by loading a few templates. The page contains:

- A header (using a header.php
  template)
- A menu (using menu.php)
- A sidebar (sidebar.php)
- A article
  (post.php)
- A tabbed area below the article
  that contains "comments", "related
  articles" and "about the author" sections (xxx.php)
- A footer
  (footer.php)

So besides xxx.php, all templates have intuitive names

Do you have any suggestions on how should I name this template, based on the content it has?

Comment: Sorry, but this really isn't a programming question and doesn't belong here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you should name it `post-meta.php`? I think it's a good name, since the file displays some information about the post.

Comment: Not really a nice name to know what info it should display. It can be anything.

Comment: @PeeHaa: you're right. I've edited my answer.

Answer (score 2):

I would call it something like post-info.php because it is related to the post it is placed under.

Answer (score 1):

Personally Id pick the name used by roles: [secondary](http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml2/mod-roleAttribute.html#col_Role) (XHTML2) or [complementary](http://dev.w3.org/html5/markup/aria/aria.html#aria.complementary) (HTML5).